# What communication system would be the easiest for an javascript game?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, nowjs-sockets

Looking at multiplayer systems to use with node.js I don't know what communication method / library is the easiest to use.

I want to be able to have some  kind of client / server authority system which is done via PHP. The user logs onto the account management system using PHP and then the User launches the client which is written in javascript that connects to the node.js server.

My question is how do I do this client / server communication and with if suggested what library. I have seen socket.io and now.js but both only have examples on how to use it without authority.

Comment: separating "javascript" into "java script" is like a sin

Comment: JavaScript, Javascript or ECMAScript, but never Java script.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look to [BrowserQuest](https://github.com/mozilla/BrowserQuest) game by Mozilla. It's open source, and it does exactly that.

Comment: But the main question is how do I do an authentication system? The user has to sign up using an PHP website and then uses the javascript client to play the game. The client communicates with the server to tell the server events which will then update the users profile in the DB

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official documentation on authorization

https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given nearly enough information on the type of game or the type of communication you need. You've mentioned Socket.IO and Now.JS, but are those a requirement? What about standard http ajax requests? Then you'll just rely on the cookie provided by the PHP session and authentication.  Is there a good reason to introduce node.js to your stack in addition to PHP?